# Page not Found when URL contains Year as parameter in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

When i navigate to URL which contains year as parameter, It goes to 404 not found Page.

My URL is as follows

`http://localhost:8080/HelloWolrd/posts/?year=2018`

And also for current year, It is working well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am facing the same problem when I was working on Calendar Plugin. Please try another name as the parameter key. Instead of `year`. you can use any name like year, years, etc.

Answer (score 2):

you can not pass `year` parameter to URL. `Year` is reserved and predefined in wordpress query variables.Please change paraameter `year` to `years` or something which is not defined as `Query vars`. Please check below url.

https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars

Answer (score 0):

Something to be aware of. This is also the case with the `GET` parameter `embed`. So `?embed=true` for example is reserved for Wordpress.